# Tuple of Jsoncpp functions

Tags: c++, c++17, jsoncpp

I am currently working with some config files, and I wanted to map options with configuration functions. So far, I have this working code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, void (Model::*)(int)> m_configMap = 
{
{ "threshold", &Model::setThreshold }
};
```

Now, as you may very well notice, this approach would not work if the input parameters were different, so I thought of adding the a parser like so (with the Jsoncpp library):

```
std::unordered_map<stsd::string, std::tuple<void(Model::*)(std::any), std::any(Json::Value*)()>> m_configMap = 
{
{ "threshold", {&Model::setThreshold, &Json::Value::asInt}}
};
```

Now, this did not work,as it was giving me an error in the brace initialiser list saying that it could not convert types. I didnt quite understand, so I tried an smaller example:

```
std::tuple<void(Model::*)(int), Json::Int (Json::Value::*)(void)> foo =
{&Model::setThreshold, &Json::Value::asInt };
```

And this is not working either. However, if I change the Json part for a string, it will work.

I am not sure of what is wrong with this, and I was wondering if someone saw something that I'm missing.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: JSon should not leak outside code which does IO operations. It almost never shouldn't be part of business logic. So thing you are doing is bad.

Comment: @MarekR Im not sure if I understand. I am just setting the values of a json to the variables of a class to have a declarative approach, and avoid a large list of if-else blocks.

Comment: That is a problem. Purpose of any JSon library is do conversion between JSon (exchanged with IO device) and data used by main logic. Only code which reads/writes data should depend on `jsoncpp` and return classes which are specific to your problem. This is matter of of good code architecture so explanation is quite complex (like a book "Clean Code" Robert C. Martin). By leak I meant that your code which reads data forces other parts of code to have dependency to jsoncpp library.

Comment: Well that was the whole point of this code. My model does not know anything about the json. It just sees the values.  It is my controller the one dealing with config parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not refering to an instance of Model, or the member function of Model is not static. I don't know about the JSON part but this should get you started. If you have questions let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Model
{
public:
    void setTreshold(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "treshold set to " << value << "\n";
    }

};


int main()
{
    Model model;

    // I prefer using string_view over string for const char* parameters
    // I also prefer using std::function over function pointers
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::function<void(int)>> m_configMap
    {{
        // the function should refer to an instance of Model, so  use a lambda 
        // not a direct function pointer
        {"threshold", [&](int value) { model.setTreshold(value); } }
    }};

    auto fn = m_configMap["threshold"];
    fn(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is basically what I'm doing, but without instantiating the model. I pass it as:
``` 
auto fn = m_configMap["threshold"];
(model.*fn)(42);
```

Comment: So, I ended up adopting this approach.
The main advantage is that allows you to deal with type casting and different objects inside your functions. 
The only counter side that I can find is the extra code that makes the config function a bit harder to find, but that is no big deal.

Comment: Its more different then difficult, I'm now so used to std::function and lambdas I find the function pointer approach harder to read ;) And as with most code you can probably hide most of the details away in functions, which always helps with readability